# Recently viewed products in sap commerce cloud

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

How can we add the recently viewed products in sap commerce cloud as it is not an ootb.
Can any one explain.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list these products based on user you can use cookie or local storage to save viewed products. Then use this cookie/localstorage to show them.